# set an alphabetic counter for environment

Tags: numbering, environments

I have a `\newtheorem` environment of the form

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

which follows the numbering of the section.

How can I change the numbering from arithmetic to alphabetic? In the middle of the document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better if you posted a full [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) as the answer might (but probably doesn't) depend on the package that you use for theorems etc. In any case, I think you need

```
\renewcommand\thetheorem{\alph{theorem}}
```

With this you obtain:

[image]

I am assuming that you only want to make the `theorem` counter alphabetic, and not the sections. Here is the full code (a MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

  \begin{theorem}first one \end{theorem}

  \renewcommand\thetheorem{\alph{theorem}}

  \begin{theorem}second one \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I do want to change the section numbering, too, but this is easy due to the `\appendix` command. Your answer is what I'm looking for, thank's a lot.